# pandas dataframe regex filtering of hierarchical columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['[mg]', '[mg] true'], index=range(3))
```

To filter for the column ending in `]`, one may use:

```
print(df.filter(regex="\]$"))
  [mg]
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

Next, consider a hierarchical columns dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1], ['[mg]', '[mg] true']]), index=range(3))
print(df1)
     0              1          
  [mg] [mg] true [mg] [mg] true
0  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
1  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
2  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
```

When I again attempt to filter for the same columns ending in `]`, it now fails:

```
print(df1.filter(regex="\]$"))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2]
```

Why does this fail, and what can I do to obtain the filtering I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains) on the [get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html#pandas-index-get-level-values) from columns then use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) to use the column index:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0, 1], ['[mg]', '[mg] true']]),
    index=range(3))

# Apply Regex to Level 1 Of the Column Index
matches = df1.columns.get_level_values(1).str.contains(r"\]$")
# Filter Using loc
filtered_df = df1.loc[:, matches]
print(filtered_df)
```

`filtered_df`:

```
     0    1
  [mg] [mg]
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Observing the pandas [source code for `.filter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/core/generic.py#L4985), pandas will supply the strings from `Dataframe._get_axis(1)` to the regex. In this case, these are tuples (*in string form*):

```
MultiIndex([(0,      '[mg]'),
            (0, '[mg] true'),
            (1,      '[mg]'),
            (1, '[mg] true')],
           )
```

So to match only `[mg]` we can modify the regex to contain the final `')`:

```py
print(df1.filter(regex=r"mg\]\'\)$"))
```

Prints:

```
     0    1
  [mg] [mg]
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
```

NOTE: Probably it's very implementation dependent. So don't do it :)

Comment: Interesting that filter is treating the tuple like a string. Wouldn't the regex just be `r"\]\'\)$"'` to match OP's current expression?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, of course. I've just added it as an example